# Filter, forEach and Push methods not working on Array in Vue prop

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects

I´m trying to do something quite simple.
I´m passing an ID as a prop from a parent component and then trying to filter the "topics" array in the child prop, only returning the topic with the same ID.

However, filtering this array does not work at all.
Even using `this.topics.filter(x => x);` returns an empty array.

`this.topics.forEach(x => console.log('working!')` won´t log anything either.

`this.topics.push("Some new Element")` resets the array completely and returns an array only including `"Some new Element"`.

`console.log(this.topics)` returns the full array, except when using the push method before - then it only returns the "new" Array containing the pushed element.

It throws no errors in the console. The array is not empty, firestore fills it without a problem (see screenshot below).

I´ve tried creating another array in the data() function, only containing strings, to see if it´s some kind of error in the file, but filtering "normal" arrays works just fine.

`this.topics` contains only objects, maybe this is the reason?

Filling the topics array in the created hook by getting the data from firebase
(Works without a problem, see screenshot below)

```
    db.collection("courses").doc(this.$route.params.course_id).collection("sections")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(sec => {
        if (this.topics.length == 0) {
          db.collection("courses").doc(this.$route.params.course_id).collection("sections").doc(sec.id).collection("topics").orderBy("order")
            .get()
            .then(snapshot => {
              snapshot.forEach(doc => {



              // Magic starts here.
                this.topics.push({
                  data: doc.data(), // <= that´s an object
                  topic_id: doc.id,
                  sectionOfTopic_id: sec.id
              // And ends here




                })
              })
            })
        } else {
          return;
        }
      })
    })
```

My data() function

```
  data() {
    return {
      courseTitle: null,
      sections: [],
      topics: [],
      selected: undefined
    }
  }
```

Me desperately trying to get it to filter in the mounted hook (also tried in methods and created hook)

```
  mounted() {
    
    console.log(this.topics)
    let preview = this.topics.filter(x => x)
    console.log(this.topics)
    console.log(preview)
}
```

Using `this.topics.filter(x => x)` I would expect to get a 1:1 copy of the array, however it´s returning an empty array `[]`.

[image: Screenshot of the array via Vue dev-tools at runtime]

Comment: It seems your `topics` array is empty. Please check that out. Running `filter` or `forEach` in an empty array returns an empty array

Comment: add `console.log`s after your various `.gets()` and see where it's going wrong

Comment: The array is not empty, it gets everything from firebase successfully, I´m posting a screenshot of the array at runtime.

Comment: **Don't use `console.log(this.topics)` to check the contents of the array.** It is misleading, especially when dealing with asynchronous code. Instead, do `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.topics))`. It sounds like you're just not waiting for the asynchronous code to finish before checking the contents of the array. The reason you may be seeing a populated array is because logging an array (as opposed to the stringified version) will be evaluated lazily, whereas stringifying it shows an accurate version of the array contents **at that line**.

Comment: Using `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.topics))` it logs `[]` every time, but I´m getting all the data from the database in the created hook and only logging it in the mounted hook, so do I still need to offset the "filtering" further? How would I do that?

Comment: I'm not a Vue expert but it sounds like `mounted()` is firing before `this.topics.push( ... )`. Your mounted function would need to await the promise that I'd expect Firebase to return.

Comment: Adding it in the .then() after firebase gets it didn´t do anything, however setTimeout to 10 Seconds seems to do the trick. Looks like it is definitely a timing issue. I´ll see if I can fix it...

Comment: Are your `console.log(this.topics)` calls in the mounted() function showing you your topics?
Also try what @Tyler Roper said.

Comment: @АлександрФишер yes, they do. @Tyler Roper is on to something, though chaining `.then()` in the creation hook gets quite complicated as I also have to get the sections array, which is created similarly. Isn´t the whole point of lifecycle hooks to wait for the hook beforehand to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more troubleshooting I have finally gotten the code to work.
Special thanks to @TylerRoper for pointing out that the problem has something to do with the code being asynchronous. 
I have assumed that Vue lifecycle hooks are also used for asynchronous operations, however this is **not the case**.

I solved the problem by adding **watch properties**:

```
  watch: {
topics: function (val) {
  this.topReady = true;
  if(this.topReady && this.secReady){
    this.allReady = true
  }
},
sections: function (val) {
  this.secReady = true;
  if(this.topReady && this.secReady){
    this.allReady = true
  }
},
allReady: function (val) {
  return this.loadPreview()
}
```

And updated the data accordingly:

```
  data() {
return {
  courseTitle: null,
  sections: [],
  topics: [],
  selected: undefined,
  topReady: false,
  secReady: false,
  allReady: false
}
```

and wrote the actions in a method **called by one of the watch properties**:

```
    loadPreview() {
  // Set previewSpecs
  let preview = this.topics.filter(top => this.previewSpecs.topic_id==top.topic_id)
  let previewSotId = preview[0].sectionOfTopic_id
  let previewSec = this.sections.filter(sec => sec.section_id==previewSotId);


  this.selected = previewSotId;
  this.choose(preview[0].topic_id, false, preview[0].sectionOfTopic_id, previewSec[0].data.name)
}
```

It all works now. Thank you to everybody who helped me sort out my first ever question on Stack Overflow!

If someone finds a better way to solve the issue, I am looking forward to your alternative.

Comment: your and @TylerRoper answer it helped me a lot. i use setTimeout function for this problem